# DB Closure function for dynamic select queries vs performance

Tags: closures, zend-framework2

I am working on reports page for a ZF2 project. Now I need to generate dynamic query depends on filters (which can be '=', '>', '>=', '<', '<=', 'IN' ). I am using DB select closure for generate where statement. But I am afraid if it could be a bottleneck in coming days ( by performance or by limitations ).

Can any body suggest if my approach is Ok or need to generate string where statements like
    `->where('A > 12 AND B < 12 AND C IN (1,2,3)')`

instead of

```
->where(function(Where $where){
    $where->equalTo('A', 10)->equalTo('B', 12)->IN('C', array(1,2,3));
});
```

Or any better idea ?

Comment: It is not look like a good idea for using closure with dynamic filters as how can we update a already built closure for a new filters as we were doing on array filters or strings statements. I very much prefer the array instead but How can we apply other that equal operator to array (like we doing in where(array('A' => 12))).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a better solution. Instead of using closure I using direct Where Object something like that

```
$where = new \Zend\Db\Sql\Where();
$where->equalTo('A', 10)->equalTo('B', 12)->IN('C', array(1,2,3));
$sql->select()->where($where);
```

It is more dynamic as $where can be dynamically updated by other values. Still if anybody have  other ideas please share.